# What is the best way to send & visualize sensor data using raspberry?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, mqtt

My gas consumption is being monitored by a RaspberryPi (using a reed sensor).

A rather simple python script is gathering the sensor output and storing it in a CSV file.

The RaspberryPi has an internet connection (WiFi).

**I want the RaspberryPi to send the sensor information somewhere where I can visualize or access the data online.
What would be the best way to do so ?**

*Seen solutions involving MQTT and AwS (Amazon), but sounds complicated to send a single variable very few seconds and store it with a timestamp...*

Any fancy simple solution ?

Thanks !

Here is the small code running as a Service

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO 
import time
import csv
from datetime import datetime

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(15, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
counter = 0

current_state = True
prev_state = True

while True:
    current_state = GPIO.input(15)
    if (current_state == False) and (prev_state == True):
        counter = counter + 1
        print(counter)
        with open('/home/pi/gas_newfile.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
            spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
            spamwriter.writerow(str(counter))
            spamwriter.writerow(str(datetime.now()))
    prev_state = current_state
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: mqtt is very simple. you will hardly find anything simpler than that. I think Adafruit has a MQTT broker and very nice tutorials on how to send/receive data from that broker

Comment: Yes, indeed. What I'm asking is more around where should I be sending the information. What is the best platform / solution to send over sensor data and then visualize / analyze it.

Comment: best is very subjective and depends entirely on your application. My suggestion is to take a look at some MQTT tutorials and try implementing this. You could also setup a server and open a socket to send info to this server, but using mqtt will be simpler than implementing your own server.

Comment: Not sure you understand my question... I want to know what are the solutions to receive / store and then visualize the information... like AWS, ThingSpeak, etc... Merely asking for people's view on what are the best-in-class solutions.

Comment: as I told you "best" is subjective and off topic for StackOverflow. What would be best for you might be completely useless for another person.

Comment: I'm voting to close because this question can only lead to opinion based answers which are considered off topic. As @SembeiNorimaki has said this sort of questions doesn't work on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Wrap a couple of lines of `flask` (or even simpler Python `http.server`) around it and it's a web-page that you can view from your smartphone or web-browser at work. Add `grafana` and you get a pretty *"dashboard'*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSV is one if  the ways to monitor data after transferring them.
If you dont need to store long-time data you can use SSH,... or cable and write a UI to displaying them.

But if you want to have long-time data you can use MySQL to create and modify a database on raspberryPi for data.

About transferring data from raspberryPi to Monitor, in addition to SSH, VNC(directly controling) ,.... or you can use some cloud Services like Amazon and Google that you mentioned befor.